# How To Create Full Screen Fixed With Scrolling Background Images

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, fullscreen, css-position

I did this before, so I know it's possible, but now it won't work and it's messing with my brain! So hopefully, before I smash all the IE's in the neighborhood to a million bits, somebody can help me out with this.

What I'm trying to do is recreate something like the [Ornamento](http://ornamento.com/) website. When the user scrolls on it, the pictures overlap each other. They are done with layered fixed background images in separate divs. The effect looks like this:

This is the website unscrolled:

[image: Ornamento Unscrolled]

And this is the website scrolled

[image: Ornamento Scrolled]

As you can see, the background image stays in the same place but is gradually overlayed, or "taken over", by the other background image in a different div. This works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE10, IE9, Safari and IE8 (probably others). It's being done with CSS3 background cover and fixed background positioning.

So, I attempted to duplicate this on my beta site, [Striking Foto](http://dejongdesign.ca/striking_foto/). I got it to work in everything except legacy IE (8 and down). I was using the IE filter for a full background image and it looked good.

I used the following code (there are 5 divs with content in them, each labeled home, about, gallery, pricing, and contact:

```
#home, #about, #gallery, #pricing, #contact { 
position: relative; 
display: block; 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
background: url(../assets/style_images/home_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover; 
border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader (src='assets/style_images/home_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/home_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}

#about { background-image: url(../assets/style_images/about_background.jpg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/about_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/about_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}

#gallery { background-image: url(../assets/style_images/gallery_background.jpg); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/gallery_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/gallery_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}

#pricing { background-image: url(../assets/style_images/pricing_background.jpg); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/pricing_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/pricing_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";}

#contact { 
background-image: url(../assets/style_images/contact_background.jpg); 
border: none;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/contact_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); 
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='assets/style_images/contact_background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; }
```

(Note: I believe this IE filter only works when the image is referenced with a link from the index file, not the CSS file. I may be wrong on this, but that's why the links aren't the same.)

I assumed this would work, but it didn't. When I scrolled in IE I saw this happening:

[image: IE8 Not Scrolling Correctly]

Instead of the fixed background positioning, the background image is scrolling. So I figured it was the IE filters because they like to fork everything up. So I removed them and tried again. This time I got the following image:

[image: IE8 Not Scaling Correctly]

Now the image scrolls right, but the background image isn't full screen.

My HTML looks like this (edited to make it smaller and more readable).

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Striking Foto</title>
 <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
 </head>

 <body>
 <header></header>

 <div id="home">
    <!--nothing except images-->
 </div>
 <div id="about">
    <div class="wrap">
        <article>
        <!--nothing except content-->
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="wrap">
        <article>
        <!--content-->
        </article>
    </div>
</div>   
<div id="pricing">
    <div class="wrap">
        <article>
        <!--content-->
        </article>
    </div>
</div>   
<div id="contact">
    <div class="wrap">
        <article>
            <!--content-->
        </article>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

And so, I am stuck. Somehow Ornamento does it in IE, and I have done it before, but I don't know how and I could really use some help. I can provide all the CSS if you'd like, but you can also just look at it online.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised with this that the images on ornamento.com are not full width. Stretch your browser as wide as you can, you'll see ;-)

The best option is to use http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ with a ie conditional and the images don't scroll in ie

or make the images big enough that the edges are not seen in ie, they will still look ok in other browsers which size as "cover"

Hope this helps anyone else who finds this! I spent hours on it